# How can i use value of a combobox in another external file to help cursor.excute to search in database? NameError: name 'combo1' is not defined

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, tkinter, module

I'm having trouble using the combobox in an external file. Basically the combobox is in the main file and I would like to use its selected value in the external file. If I select a certain item, it should help `cursor.excute` to search for a database table, so `cursor.execute("SELECT x FROM Table1 WHERE element = ?", (combo1,))`

As you can see, the combobox `combo1` is present in the main file and is not detected by the B.py file where cursor.excute is located. I get the error:

```
    cursor.execute("SELECT x FROM Table1 WHERE element = ?", (combo1,))
NameError: name 'combo1' is not defined
```

How can I solve the problem? Can you show me the code? I'm new to Python

**Main file**

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

from two import *

window = tk.Tk()  
window.geometry("350x200")
style = ttk.Style(window)

combo1=ttk.Combobox(window, width = 22)
combo1['value'] =["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
combo1.place(x=10, y=10)
combo1.set("Select")

btn = Button(window, text="Click")
btn.place(x=10, y=80)
```

**B.py**

```
import sqlite3

def function_ext():

    #recover value
    con = sqlite3.connect('/home/jack/Desktop/database.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT x FROM Table1 WHERE element = ?", (combo1,))
    select = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need to `import tkinter as tk` *and* `from tkinter import *` (and realistically, you **shouldn't** do this). It's best to just use `import tkinter as tk` and then access tk widgets like `tk.Button`, `tk.Entry`, etc. [Star imports are usually a bad idea](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-import-star-in-python-is-a-bad-idea/)

Comment: @JRiggles What is the difference in using tk.Button and Button as in my code? Why are there two ways to use tkinter? P.S: the code of your answer I try it after which now I can't, then I accept after your answer

Comment: There really is no difference, but simply instantiating `Button` only works if you do `from tkinter import *`. Whereas `tk.Button` works because of `import tkinter as tk` (the "as **tk**" part is where the `tk.` namespace prefix comes from). The problem with star imports is that if any other module you're importing *also* has a class called `Button` -for example-, the interpreter won't know which `Button` you're referring to (tkinter or some other module), so it's best to namespace things appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to modify `function_ext` to accept `combo1` as a parameter like so

```
def function_ext(combobox):  # add the parameter
    #recover value
    con = sqlite3.connect('/home/jack/Desktop/database.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    # use the 'combobox' param here and .get() the value (thanks acw1668)
    cursor.execute("SELECT x FROM Table1 WHERE element = ?", (combobox.get(),))
    select = cursor.fetchone()
```

Then in your `Main.py` file you need to import `function_ext`

```
from B.py import function_ext
```

then you can call `function_ext` from `Main.py`

```
...
combo1=ttk.Combobox(window, width = 22)
combo1['value'] =["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
combo1.place(x=10, y=10)
combo1.set("Select")
...
function_ext(combo1)  # call the function using 'combo1' as the parameter
```

For what it's worth, the `NameError` you've been getting is caused because your `B.py` file has no idea that your `Main.py` file exists, and therefore has no idea what `combo1` is. Essentially, there's nothing in `B.py` named `combo1`, so you can't refer to anything with that name without getting an error.

Comment: So the solution is to simply import the function_ext function into the main file and then pass the combo1 parameter to the function_ext function? Don't you need anything else? I thought the solution was more difficult. Later I'll try your code and I'll let you know. Thank you

Comment: Yep, if you have functions defined in other files you'll want to import those into `Main.py` and call them there! You have to pass in `combo1` from `Main.py` as a parameter because otherwise `B.py` has no way of accessing it.

Comment: `combobox.get()` should be used instead of just `combobox` inside `function_ext()`.

Comment: @acw1668 That's true! I'll fix it!

Comment: @acw1668 combo1 seems to work anyway. why should i use combo1.get()? What is the difference? thank you

Comment: @JRiggles A thousand thanks. I accepted your answer. I posted another very similar question (I use the same code as this question): if you don't get bored, can you help me? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74074461/retrieve-variable-from-the-database-of-an-external-file-error-nameerror-name