# How to split up different Tkinter windows into different modules?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-module

I have building an Tkinter app with multiple windows and each window having many functions. For that, I have made a different module containing the functions and variables and the GUI in another module. Here's an example to make you understand better.

**gui.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from func import *

root = Tk()

lbl = Label(root, text="Enter your name:")
lbl.pack()
ent = Entry(root)
ent.pack()
btn = Button(root, text='Update', command=update_text)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**func.py**

```
varbool = True

def update_text():
    a = ent.get()
    lbl['text'] = f"Hello! {a}"
    btn['bg'] = 'red'
    print(varbool)
```

Now, when I run `gui.py`, I get the following error:

`NameError: name 'ent' is not defined`

Is there any way to resolve this?

And also, is there any way to maybe have a `main.py` to link all the modules?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74072555/how-can-i-use-value-of-a-combobox-in-another-external-file-to-help-cursor-excute/74072659#74072659) help?

Comment: Yes, kind of. 
Basically I have to use the variables as arguments and pass the widget variables in `gui.py` as parameters.
However, a more detailed answer would help. Also thanks for helping.

Comment: Yeah, that's the gist of it

Comment: Is there any other way? Since each function will have many arguments and the code will get messy.

Comment: Hard to say. It's generally best practice to handle all of your frontend stuff in your main Python file and use modules for things like functions and UI components. Spreading your UI code across multiple files is asking for headaches down the road.